Global KieSession for Sliding Window Rules Becomes Null in Spark Streaming with Drools
I'm working on a Scala project using Spark Streaming and Drools, and I have an issue with the global KieSession that I initialized for sliding window rules. I fetch sliding window rules from a database, create a KieSession, and make it global so that it can be accessed across different streaming batches. I use a different kiesession for other rules and dispose it right after firing the rules. However, when I try to access this global KieSession to fire the rules, it always becomes null.
Relevant code:
@transient lazy val globalKieSessionRef: AtomicReference[KieSession] = new AtomicReference[KieSession](null)
var deviceList: List[String] = List.empty[String]

def initializeGlobalKieSession(): Unit = {
  val (allSlidingWindowRules, devices) = fetchSlidingWindowRules()
  deviceList = devices

  val kieSession = createKieSessionWithRules(allSlidingWindowRules)
  globalKieSessionRef.set(kieSession)
}

def createKieSessionWithRules(drl: String): KieSession = {
  val kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get()
  val kieHelper = new KieHelper()

  val rules = "import com.sample.model.RuleTemplate\n" + drl
  kieHelper.addContent(rules, org.kie.api.io.ResourceType.DRL)

  val kieBaseConfiguration = kieServices.newKieBaseConfiguration()
  kieBaseConfiguration.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM)

  val kieBase = kieHelper.build(kieBaseConfiguration)

  kieBase.newKieSession()
}

def Start_RuleEngine(): Unit = {
  initializeGlobalKieSession()

  // Timer to recreate the global KieSession every 30 minutes
  val timer = new java.util.Timer()
  val task = new java.util.TimerTask {
    def run(): Unit = recreateGlobalKieSession()
  }
  timer.schedule(task, 0, 30 * 60 * 1000)

  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("SparkSQL")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val Delta_table_location = sys.env.getOrElse("DELTA_TABLE", "")
  val read_deltatable = spark.readStream.delta(Delta_table_location)

  val process_deltatable = read_deltatable.writeStream.foreach(new ForeachWriter[Row] {
    def open(partitionId: Long, epochId: Long): Boolean = true

    def process(value: Row): Unit = {
      val Telemetery = value.getString(0)
      val jsonObj = new JSONObject(Telemetery)
      val Deviceid = jsonObj.getString("DeviceId")

      if (deviceList.contains(Deviceid)) {
        val globalKieSession = globalKieSessionRef.get()
        if (globalKieSession != null) {
          fireKieSession(globalKieSession, jsonObj, Deviceid)
        }
      }

      val rules = GetApprovedDroolRule(Deviceid)
      val kieSession = createKieSessionWithRules(rules)
      fireKieSession(kieSession, jsonObj, Deviceid)
      kieSession.dispose()
    }

    def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {}
  })

  process_deltatable.start().awaitTermination()
}

Initialization Order: I ensured that the global KieSession is initialized before starting the Spark session.
Synchronization: I tried synchronizing the blocks of code that access or modify the KieSession to prevent concurrency issues.
@transient: I used @transient to avoid serialization errors.
Step-by-Step Debugging: I tried running the code line by line in the Spark shell to see where the KieSession might be getting lost.
Despite these efforts, the globalKieSession still becomes null when accessed during streaming. Any insights on why this might be happening or how to resolve this issue?

You explicitly flagged the sessionRef as transient, so its value won't be "shared" between driver and executors. You may want to use the concept of Broadcast to initialize the sessionRef once and share it with executors. But I wonder if it really make sense? Can such a KieSession be used across several JVM? Anyway, I don't know precisely these stuff but you want to read about initializing/sharing variables over driver/executors.

@GaëlJ - Thank you for your response!
I understand your point about Broadcast variables. However, since we're running the Spark application locally, everything runs in a single JVM, and there is no distributed nature to the execution.
